# mongodb query search inside array PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to query on a specific key in a mongodb, however I keep ending up with empty results while it should be returning 1 record. I have looked at different questions which are basically the same but their answers haven't helped me.

I got the following structure in my mongo for example

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bb7388354f02b041b6819b2"
    },
    "raw": {
        "etag": "W/\"CQAAABYADtqt1sMfi5R4onmiTyvUAALqHFp9\"",
        "id": "abcdefg"
    }
}
```

I currently have tried the following query:

```
$id = "5bb7388354f02b041b6819b2";
$this->collection->find(['_id' => ['$oid' => $id]]);
```

However this returns an error

```
unknown operator: $oid
```

Now whatever I try, it either returns "unknown operator" or it returns nothing. I also tried switching the query and using the ID inside raw as follow.

```
$id = "abcdefg";
$this->collection->find(['raw' => ['id' => $id]]);
```

but this returns nothing for me. So I was wondering, what it is i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_id in MongoDB is not a string but ObjectId so you have to pass it right to query

```
$this->collection->find(['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id)])
```

Comment: So simple, so correct.. I feel so stupid now :) thanks! I'll accept your answer since you also included the ObjectID class.

Answer (score 1):

`$oid` is not the field. It is just a denotation that it's an mongodb `ObjectId`

So you can simply try this

```
$this->collection->find([ '_id' => $id ])
```

or

```
$this->collection->find([ 'raw.id' => $id ])
```

Comment: Thanks this worked flawlessly, but seeing as the other person was 2 minutes faster with a pretty much the same answer I'd give the accepted to him, but both will get my upvotes!